# No llena ListView con ñ o tildes Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview

No logro poder mostrar las *ñ* y las tildes en mi listview.
Este es el código del parse

```
try
        {

        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jo=null;
        asistencias.clear();
        Asistencia asistencia;
        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            String nombre=new String(jo.getString("nombre").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
            //String nombre=jo.getString("nombre");
            String codigo=jo.getString("codigo");
            String imageUrl = jo.getString("imageurl");

            asistencia = new Asistencia();

            asistencia.setNombre(nombre);
            asistencia.setCodigo(codigo);
            asistencia.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

            asistencias.add(asistencia);

        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y este es el PHP

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($query){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    //$data[]=array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
    $data[]=($row);
}
//echo(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
echo(json_encode($data));
}else{
    echo('Not Found ');
}
```

Comment: ¿Te muestra algo? ¿Caracteres raros? ¿Revisaste que en tu tabla si están correctamente? Lo ideal es que los campos de tu tabla tengan el atributo `collate utf8_bin`, ejemplo: `nombre varchar(10) collate utf8_bin` y en tu consulta también, es decir, `WHERE nombre= 'José núñez' collate utf8_bin` de esa manera puedes insertar y mostrar datos . En cuanto a JSON puedes usar `echo utf8_decode($data);` o bien: `echo json_encode($data); `
`echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: yo tuve el mismo problema es por que uno si haces por sqlite aveces no lo reconoce los caracteres especiales, he intente hacer un order by donde el order by hice un cambio de Ñ por n y me mostraba normal, ahora si haras por JSON te recomiendo revisar l

Comment: Creo que deberías revisar si puedes usar caracteres especiales directamente en tu base de datos

Comment: UTF 8 en todos lados.

Comment: Ya solucione e problema creo que era con la BD, lo subi a  hostinger y ahora esta de maravilla

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre que hagas es obligar al PHP a devolver el json con carácteres unicode escapados, eso lo haces de la siguiente manera:

```
echo(json_encode($data, JSON_ESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Con esto si llegas a migrar de nuevo tu base de datos ya no te debería de dar el problema.